# Is it possible to add a 'pending' subscriber to Mailchimp via the API?

Tags: mailchimp

### Here's what I'd like to do:

- User completes sign up form on my app
- My app sends the input data (email address, name, etc) to Mailchimp via the API, but with a status of 'pending'
- My app sends an email to the user asking them to confirm their email address (essentially emulating the Mailchimp confirmation email)
- User clicks link in confirmation email, which takes them back to a confirmation page in my app
- My app updates the user's status in Mailchimp to 'subscribed' via the API

Essentially, I want to emulate Mailchimps standard confirmation process, but sending the emails from my own app.

The part that I don't know how to do (or don't know if it's possible) is the part where I add a new subscriber with a status of 'pending'.

Here's some further info that's not strictly relevant but may be of interest...

### Why don't I just use the standard Mailchimp confirmation email?

The confirmation email needs to contain extra info, unique to each user, that Mailchimp will not have access to.

### Why don't I collect all the data locally and then send it all to Mailchimp once the user has confirmed their email address?

For reasons I won't go into, the number and type of required fields will be unknown. At the point when the sign up form is displayed, I will request the list of fields from Mailchimp and display the necessary fields.  It is possible that, between the time when the user initially completes the form and the time when the user confirms via email, the required fields will have been changed.  If I try to submit the previously collected data to Mailchimp after the required fields have been changed, it will cause an error.

So I need to collect and submit all data to Mailchimp at the same time.  And then simply 'switch on' that user in Mailchimp once (s)he has confirmed.

I hope I've provided enough info.  If not, happy to provide more or clarify any points.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The internal "pending" status is not able to be managed manually like that. You can subscribe them using double opt-in and then later force them onto the "subscribed" list, but you can't stop them from getting MailChimp's own confirmation email.

One possible work-around would be to add an interest group or merge field that is populated by your system once you've confirmed the email address. You'd then create a saved segment for only confirmed users and make sure you only ever send to that segment and never the whole list.

Another possibility, if you use API v3.0 (which is currently only in [beta](https://github.com/mailchimp/APIv3-examples/wiki)), is to add them to your list as unsubscribed and then switch their status to "subscribed" once you've confirmed them. If you do this, be very careful that you're not re-subscribing users who unsubscribed or you could wind up in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This workflow is definitely 100% possible in the current (V3) of the API. Just set the "status" field on a member to "pending" and then to "subscribed".

Comment: having tried this, i find that mailchimp will send its own confirmation email. questioner wants to suppress the mailchimp one

Comment: +hawbsl in mailchimp audience settings you can toggle enable auto opt in